# How to run down a list with recursion?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion, append

At first, I had to do it without recursion (just by looping which is pretty easy).

Now I have to do it with recursion, but I am not allowed to use any loop.

I guess I have to run down the list with recursion, but I don't quite understand what should be my base, or the reduction...

```
def long_strings_rec(strings, N):
    '''
    strings - a list of strings
    N - an integer
    Returns all strings in 'strings' of length bigger then 'N'
    (This function is recursive and does not use loops)
    '''

    # Your code for question #2 (second function) starts here

    # Your code for question #2 (second function) ends here
```

Any ideas? Can I have maybe an example of how to use recursion to take actions on lists indexes?

I used the helper function to do that, like @7stud suggested:

```
def helper (strings, K, results):
    if len(strings) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(strings[0]) > K:
        results.append(strings[0])
        strings.pop(0)
    else:
        strings.pop(0)
    helper(strings, K, results)
    return results


def long_strings_rec (strings, N):
    '''
    strings - a list of strings
    N - an integer
    Returns all strings in 'strings' of length bigger then 'N'
    (This function is recursive and does not use loops)
    '''

    # Your code for question #2 (second function) starts here
    return helper(strings, N, [])
    # Your code for question #2 (second function) ends here
```

Worked like a charm. Hope it's not buggy.

Comment: Take the first element of the list, and then throw the rest of the list to the function itself until the list is empty.

Comment: *what should be my base* =>  `len(strings) == 0`

Comment: @omeinusch  gave your advise a try. edited the question

Comment: A hint that will make things easier is to use what's called an *accumulator*. Have  `long_strings(strings, N)` do one thing: call `helper(strings, N, [])` and return the result of that function, then define helper() like this: `def helper(strings, N, results)`.  Inside helper(), you can append() a string to results, then recursively call `helper(strings, N, results)`.  But recursion is hard, so don't worry about it if you can't do it.

Comment: *can i have maybe an example of how to use recursion to take actions on lists indexes?* Just use `pop()` to remove a string from strings, then if string qualifies append() string to results(the list shown in the previous comment), then recursively call `helper(strings, N, results)`

Comment: See my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505735/recursive-function-for-tracing-deletable-primes-python-3/33505960#33505960) for a short intro to recursive functions that collect results into lists..

Comment: If you're writing this for an assignment, the instructor is going to be looking for understanding of recursion, i.e. identifying the base case, partitioning input into current and rest, and forward-feeding the results while recursing. The code, as-is, doesn't say that you obviously understand (besides not giving the right result).  To communicate your understanding you should put the current element into a variable, clearly mark the base case with a comment, and clearly mark the recursive call(s) and what it is being recursed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use an `accumulator`:

```
def sum(nums):
    return helper(nums, 0)  #0 is the initial value for the accumulator

def helper(nums, total):    #total is the accumulator
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return total
    else:
        num = nums.pop()
        return helper(nums, total+num) 


print sum([1, 2, 3])

--output:--
6
```

Basically, you redefine sum() so that it takes an additional accumulator parameter variable, then have sum() call the new function.

See if you can apply those principles to your problem.

As bjorn pointed out in the comments, you could do it like this too:

```
def mysum(nums, total=0):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return total
    else:
        num = nums.pop()
        return sum(nums, total+num) 


print mysum([1, 2, 3])

--output:--
6
```

Comment: `def helper(nums, total=0)` ?

Comment: @thebjorn, Well, then it should be: `def sum(nums, total=0)` :)

Comment: Nah.. I wouldn't override `sum` ;-)

Comment: Well, then `my_sum(nums, total=0)`!

Comment: @Beginner, when `len(strings)==0` you don't want to return 0--after all the reason you are calling the function is to get a list of long strings back.  Instead, you want to return the list of long strings.  If you initialize the `results` accumulator with a list(How would you do that?), then your function can append() qualifying strings to `results`, and then `results` will contain the long strings.

Comment: @Beginner. Look at the sum example I posted, and use it as a template for your problem.  You are only going to have two branches: an if clause and an else clause--just like the sum example.